# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable in connecting - Arangodb - Python

Tags: python, connection, arangodb

I want to use [pyarango](https://github.com/tariqdaouda/pyArango)-library in python to connect to arrangodb, but I cannot even get connected. Here is the code using python 2.7:

```
from pyArango.connection import Connection

conn = Connection()
conn.createDatabase(name = "test_db")
db = self.conn["test_db"] #all databases are loaded automatically into the connection and are accessible in this fashion
collection = db.createCollection(name = "users") #all collections are also loaded automatically
# collection.delete() # self explanatory
```

And this is the error I get:

```
  File "pyarango-test1.py", line 8, in
    conn = Connection(arangoURL='http://localhost:8529') #or with just conn = Connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyArango/connection.py", line 19, in init
    self.reload()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyArango/connection.py", line 27, in reload
    data = r.json()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I can't find any related threads on it, can somebody help me with this?

Solution:

I first did a: `pip install requests`
and got:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

But it wasnt sufficient...so I had to upgrade it/force it:

```
    sudo pip install --upgrade requests 
    and got: 
    Collecting requests from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/r/requests/requests-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=11dc91bc96c5c5e0b566ce8f9c9644ab Downloading requests-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (464kB) 100% |################################| 466kB 3.6MB/s Installing collected packages: requests Found existing installation: requests 0.12.1 Uninstalling requests-0.12.1: Successfully uninstalled requests-0.12.1

Successfully installed requests-2.5.1
```

Now it connects, and the self.conn[etc].. I just deleted the: self. and went like this:

```
try:
    conn.createDatabase(name = "test_db2")
except Exception as e:
    print "conn could not createDatabase(name = test_db)"
    print e
```

And it worked!! THANK YOU MARTIJN!!!

nb! the error I mentioned last was only because the db already existed.

Comment: You are using an older version of the `requests` library. Is this on Ubuntu? Is `python-requests` system installed and version 0.8.x perhaps?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what the requests library is actually. This is kali linux/debian wheezy-base. So I will try to install python-requests system...be back

Comment: With pip install requests - It said this: Successfully installed requests-2.5.1
But then another error occures: NameError: name 'self' is not defined
Seems it cant recognize the:  self.conn[etc..]

Comment: Thanks for the issue, I've updated the setup.py so that pyArango now requires requests>=2.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

Your error indicates that you are using an old `requests` version; `response.json()` became a method in [`requests` version 1.0](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#100-2012-12-17). Your local installation predates this.

Either you have an old release installed as an OS package, or by you yourself. You need to upgrade that package.